# How does binding work for layered inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I have a virtual class:

```
class Tester {
  virtual void Validate();
}

class Test1 : Tester {
  void Validate(...) {
    /implementation
  }
}

class Test2 : Test1 {
  void Validate(...) {
    /implementation
  }
}
```

To my understanding, the virtual should make it dynamic binding. But I'm uncertain what would happen if we have layered classes (ie. Test2 inheriting Test1 inheriting Tester):

```
void RunTest(Tester test) {
  test.Validate(...);
}

...
Test2 test_candidate = Test2();
RunTest(test_candidate)
```

Which `Validate` method would this call?

Comment: By using `...` as in `void Validate(...)` you are indicating that the parameters may/are be different from the virtual function in `class Tester`.  If this is the case then  `void Validate(...)` does not override then function in  `class Tester` and instead hides it's name for the purposes of name lookup

Comment: You have slicing in your code. There will be no virtual calls there at all.

Comment: What is stopping you from testing it and checking it out? It's really simple and something you can easily do yourself. Observe the results and then ask if you have questions about the results.

Comment: I assume the `...` is not the actual parameter list, but simply indicates the parameters are omitted.

Comment: Is something stopping you from trying and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void RunTest(Tester test)
> ```

This  parameter of the function is an object of type `Tester`. It isn't a `Test1` nor is it a `Test2`, hence the call cannot be to anything other than `Tester::Validate`.

When you pass `Test2` as an argument, it will be converted to `Tester` by copying the base sub object.

Virtual dispatch requires indirection. You must call the function through a reference or a pointer, because only a reference or a pointer can point to a base subobject of a derived object.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to your question

(see below or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70085424/4121151) why your example code does not behave like this)

### Behaviour of "late" binding

Late binding always invokes the most specialized virtual function of the instance-type. In your case, all classes, `Tester`, `Test1` and `Test2` would invoke their own `Validate()`, as `Test` and `Test2` override this function in each subclass.

However, if you would have

```
Test3 : public Test1 { /* Not overriding Validate() */ }
```

calling `Validate()` on an instance of `Test3` would call `Test1::Validate()`, as that is the most specialized virtual implementation (it overrides `Tester::Validate()`).

## Problem in your example code

In your example code, the function `RunTest(Tester)` passes the argument [by value](https://cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/). If you pass an argument of type `Test1`, it makes a temporary copy of type `Tester`, as indicated by [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70085424/4121151), and if your compiler allows it at all without warning. This temporary copy is used in `RunTest(Tester)` and will always call `Tester::Validate()`, and that might not be the implementation of the object you passed as an argument to `RunTest(Tester)`.

To use late binding, you should pass a reference or a pointer:

```
RunTest(Tester *t) { t->Validate(); }
```

or

```
RunTest(Tester &t) { t->Validate(); }
```

Using one of these will ensure that the behaviour is as described above (your answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the code you provided:

##### 1. Private Inheritance + Private Function Definitions

You need to declare your methods as public to be able to call them from an external function like `RunTest`. Also you probably want to inherit publicly in this case, so you can cast your `Test2` class back to a `Tester`.

e.g.:

```cpp
class Tester {
public:
  virtual void Validate();
};

class Test1 : public Tester {
public:
  void Validate();
};

class Test2 : public Test1 {
public:
  void Validate();
};
```

##### 2. A few recommendations

If you want to override a virtual method in a child class, you can use `override` to mark your function as such. That way you'll get a compile-time error in case the function couldn't be overriden (e.g. because of mismatched arguments)
(I'm assuming you meant `void Validate() {}` instead of `void Validate(...)`)

Also if your classes contain any virtual methods, it's always a good idea to also provide a virtual destructor. (to properly clean up all the members in case it gets deleted by a pointer to its baseclass)

e.g.:

```cpp
class Tester {
public:
  virtual void Validate() {
      // TODO
  }
  virtual ~Tester() = default;
};

class Test1 : public Tester {
public:
  void Validate() override {
      // TODO 
  }
};

class Test2 : public Test1 {
public:
  void Validate() override {
      // TODO
  }
};
```

##### 3. The `RunTest()` function will slice the Test2 object

You're passing a `Tester` instance to `RunTest()` **by value**.
This will result in the object being [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), i.e. you'll loose everything stored in the derived objects.

```cpp
void RunTest(Tester test);

// this
Test2 t2;
RunTest(t2);

// is equivalent to:
Test2 t2;
Test t = t2;
RunTest(t);
```

so essentially you're calling the `RunTest()` method with just a `Test` object, not `Test2`.

you can fix this by either bassing by reference or by pointer:

```cpp
void RunTest(Tester& test) {}
// or
void RunTest(Tester* test) {}
```

---

##### Working Example

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Tester {
public:
  virtual void Validate() {
      std::cout << "Tester Validate" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Tester() = default;
};

class Test1 : public Tester {
public:
  void Validate() override {
      std::cout << "Test1 Validate" << std::endl;
      Tester::Validate();
  }
};

class Test2 : public Test1 {
public:
  void Validate() override {
      std::cout << "Test2 Validate" << std::endl;
      Test1::Validate();
  }
};

void RunTest(Tester& test) {
    test.Validate();
}

int main() {
    Test2 t;
    RunTest(t);
}
```

[test it on godbolt!](https://godbolt.org/z/sfsfeoGrT)